# Possible point of inflection?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Heyy guys! I have been solving multiple kinds of curve sketching questions when it comes using the first derivative and second derivative. I was curious to know why we call the point of inflection a possible point of inflection. Is there a time when the point of inflection may not really be a point of inflection when solving for my second derivative at 0? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You only have an actual point of inflection where the second derivative is zero and changes sign.

It is possible that $f''(x) = 0 $ and there is no point of inflection.

A simple example is $f(x)=x^4$ whose second derivative is always positive. $f''(0)=0$ but $(0,0)$ is not a point of inflection.